# Prove: $f=f_1+f_2$, and this division is unique.

Tags: complex-analysis

> $\Omega$ is two connected domain, $\partial \Omega=C_2-C_1$, $C_2$ and $C_1$ are two closed contours. $f$ is holomorphic in $\Omega$ and continuous in $\overline\Omega$. Prove: there exists $f_1$ is analytic outside of $C_1$ and $f_2$ is analytic inside $C_2$ suuch that $f=f_1+f_2$. And this division is unique.

I think maybe I can conformally map the domain onto an annulus, but now can I do it in detail? Also, in order to prove division is unique, show I suppose another division $f=f_3+f_4$, then prove $f_1=f_3, f_2=f_4$? Any hint will be appreciated. Thanks!